# AJAX call in react doesnt log anythin in console nor it shows anything in div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I have a index.html file where i have included these scripts near body tag and this div tag.

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<!-- Load our React component. -->
<script type="text/jsx" src="getrepodata.js"></script>
```

In getrepodata i try to make an ajax call with react, but it doesnt show anything in console log of index.html file connected onto a local server from xampp

```
'use strict';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        items: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: result.items
                });
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
        )
console.log(items);
}

render() {
    
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
       
        return (
            console.log("foo");
            console.log(item);
            <ul>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.name} {item.price}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, domContainer);
```

I have looked everywhere and havent found a solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in the "Network" tab of the developer tools to see if the request has gone through?

Comment: @MosheKatz Yes, nothing is shown there either. If i change this code to for ex "do this if someone clicks on this button" then react code works, so nothing is wrong with that. Problem is rather somewhere in this code

Comment: Lots of small errors: https://jsfiddle.net/qo25sLuw/ 1) you're trying to use `result.items` which doesn't exist 2) you're logging `items` which doesn't exist 3) you're rendering `{item.name}` which doesn't exist, 4) you're loading `todos/1` which is a single item, not an array, etc.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, so ive tried it and still doesnt log to console the "items" from console.log(items) in code in fiddle. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your fetch callback uses `result` so you need to log that. And putting it inside `return(...)` is a syntax error. You'd need to put it after `else {`, before returning the JSX. Like I do in the fiddle, which logs the Array to the console just fine.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, ive literally copied your code from fiddle, see that it works there, but when i try it in visual studio then update browser and check console log it doesnt show it there. Thanks for your help anyway, i have to look into this further. I get an error after few seconds message port closed before response received so

Comment: That's probably from the hot-reloading server, when you manually refresh the browser. You can ignore that. You say the Network doesn't show anything. It should at the very least show the browser loading the scripts.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes it does load the react scripts and other stuff, but not this one. Do you have any suggestion on what i should do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you upload your project as-is on github so we can take a look?

Comment: @ChrisG I found out the what the problem was. I had to insert these scripts instead of the ones i have currently: <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>, Maybe this helps someone!

Comment: Right, you definitely need babel for that `type="text/jsx"` script to be translated first. The browser doesn't support JSX natively. I recommend using create-react-app to skip the hassle.